# What is best practice in Python, when using Boolean values vs "normal" values?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, boolean, pep8

As a complete beginner can´t figure out, what the best practice would be to write code out of the given examples.
I feel like I want to avoid the use of Boolean as much as possible, as it gives me less readability and control over the code.

I really want to learn to write really good clean code right from the start.

I tried with Boolean.
Without Boolean.
and with fewer variables.

## School example:

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("YOU LOSE!")
else:
    print("YOU WIN!")
```

## Example 2: without Boolean.

```
secret_word = "another"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess != secret_word:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
        if guess == secret_word:
            print("YOU WIN!")
    else:
        print("YOU LOSE!")
        break
```

## Example 3: Stripped down code with only 3 variables

```
secret_word = "another"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0

while guess != secret_word:
    if guess_count < 3:
        guess = input("enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
        if guess == secret_word:
            print("YOU WIN!")
    else:
        print("YOU LOSE")
        break
```

In the school example, the linter remarks there is redundant parentheses, in the Boolean value, in the while statement.

Comment: Best practice questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow as the answers to them will be based on opinions, not facts. I suggest either asking something more specific or posting your full code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com where you can also ask this question between the lines. See [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing)

Comment: I was actually not sure about that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in your case it is better to break the loop if you got it right.
Limiting the max number of loop iterations is mostly done with for loops and range.

```
secret_word = "another"
max_guesses = 3

for guess_cnt in range(max_guesses):
    guess = input("enter guess: ")

    if guess == secret_word:
        break

if guess == secret_word:
    print("YOU WIN!")
else:
    print("YOU LOSE")
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It is most appreciated.